В каком типе файлов лучше хранить данные об игровом мире и как их сохранять?
Всем привет, делаю 2D-проект на движке Godot. Хочу создать мир в виде клеток (как в Terraria, Mindustry и др.). Решил я делать мир из клеток, клетки группировать в чанки (32х32 клеток) и из чанков делать мир.
Мир сделал, генерацию настроил. Осталось только сохранять мир и данные о нем, о измененных клетках и его текущем состоянии, например, что где-то там поставили печка, она работала и когда мы зайдём обратно, то эта печка должна работать, причем с тем же прогрессом, мол в прошлой сессии было уже переплавлено 50%, значит и в этой сессии переплавка начинается с 50%.
Но я не знаю как сохранять это и в каком виде. В моем опыте имеется только проекты с JSON-файлами и ещё видел Toml, но не думаю, что они подойдут (поправьте если есть вариант реализации).
Помогите пожалуйста, какой тип данных лучше использовать и как с ним работать на С#?

Почему JSON не подойдёт? Структуры данных, которые надо сохранять, покажете?

Конкретной структуры ещё нет, но нужно сохранять следующее: Позицию по Х и Y у клетки в чанке, в котором он находится. Айди ресурса клетки и тип клетки (воздух, твердая клетка, пустота). Так нужно сохранить каждый блок, а каждый блок находится в разных чанках (в одном чанке 32х32 клеток), а чанков на карте планируют сделать для начала 32х32 также.
